# Why does the rank have to be $n$ for a QR-factorization to exist?

Tags: linear-algebra

The title says it all: For an $m \times n$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$, rank $\mathbf{A}$ would have to be $n$ for a QR-factorization to exist - why?

Comment: If $A$ is the zero matrix, we can take $Q$ the identity (which is orthogonal)  and $R$ the zero matrix (which is upper triangular). So the rank condition is not required

Comment: But my book, "linear algebra for engineers and scientists", states that "Let $\mathbf{A}$ be an $m \times n$ matrix such that rank $\mathbf{A} = n$. Then $\mathbf{A}$ has a factorization $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{Q}\mathbf{R}$

Comment: The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) suggests the rank requirement can be dropped, although some uniqueness is lost. I suspect the rank requirement is included in the book to make the construction more straight forward.